# Как через input() ввести данные в одну строку вместе с задаваемым текстом python

Tags: python

Требуется написать так, чтобы выводилось "Введите число часов (ввод) и минут (ввод) для сна"
Как это сделать? Возможно ли?
Не хочется вводить данные в две строки. Видела реализацию с использованием slpit(), но там не требовалось выводить текст для пользователя

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h, m = map(
    int,
    input("Введите число часов и минут для сна через пробел: ").split()
)
```

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
> [GCC 8.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> h, m = map(
> @...     int,
> @...     input("Введите число часов и минут для сна через пробел: ").split()
> @... )
> @Введите число часов и минут для сна через пробел: 10 11
> @>>> h, m
> (10, 11)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
hours_minutes = input('Введите число часов и минут для сна:').split(":")
print(hours_minutes)
```

Вводим: `10:20`

Результат: `['10', '20']`

Answer (score 0):

Может так подойдет:

```
hours, minutes = input('Введите число часов: '), input('Введите число минут: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Введите число часов и минут для сна:')
h_m = input()

h = h_m[0]+h_m[1]
m = h_m[0-2]+h_m[-1]


print(h, m)
```

Как то так.